# Sticky Eclipse error markers

Tags: java, eclipse

After a clean and rebuild there are error markers in Eclipse Problems view, although everything should be OK.

How can I remove this inconsistent errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I answer myself the next steps worked for me:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Delete /.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects//.markers for all affected projects.
3. Run eclipse.exe -clean & close

The steps above resolved my case; steps 4. and 5. are mentioned on the wiki, but were not necessary to solve my problems:

1. Run Eclipse and load the workspace.
2. Clean all affected projects.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can just right click on the problem in the Problems View and choose `Delete`.